# Does Terraform have an Azure ARM "complete" mode?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

We are looking to "reset" a resource group, deleting everything but the necessary infrastructure in it. The problem is we are still immature in our IAC practices and a lot of resources are deployed via the portal. My initial thought is to have the only necessary infra defined in an ARM template and running it in complete mode when we want to reset it. Does Terraform have a complete mode feature? From what I understand, Terraform will only manage stuff in state. Since we wont really respecting the state after initial deployment, the resources deployed via the portal wont be destroyed on a TF destroy. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Terraform have a complete mode feature?

AFAIK, No , Terraform doesn't have complete Mode like ARM template has.

> From what I understand, Terraform will only manage stuff in state.
> Since we wont really respecting the state after initial deployment,
> the resources deployed via the portal wont be destroyed on a TF
> destroy.

Yes , You are correct the Terraform will only manage the the
resources which are in state file only .

So, by default Terraform will only store the resources deployed through it in the state file but if you want to create some resources from the portal , then also you can use the `import resources` feature of terraform. Using which Terraform will be able to manage the resources created from Terraform and Portal as well.

**Reference:**

[Import - Terraform by HashiCorp](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/import/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, Terraform does not have such a feature.

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/26558) which mainly covers the "reporting" aspect, but also would allow acting upon it.

You might be able to build something around the `import` feature of Terraform, as suggested [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27815). However, this would require some effort.

You could also use Terraform to deploy an [ARM template in complete mode](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group_template_deployment), but then you might loose most of why you wanted to use Terraform in the first place.